# Finding element in embedded array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection students look like this:

```js
{
    "_id" : 10,
    "name" : "Christiano Ronaldo",
    "scores" : [
            {
                    "type" : "exam",
                    "score" : 40.58945534169687
            },
            {
                    "type" : "quiz",
                    "score" : 4.30461571152303
            },
            {
                    "type" : "homework",
                    "score" : 62.36309025722009
            },
            {
                    "type" : "homework",
                    "score" : 32.1707802903173
            }
    ]
}
```

How do I find out the lowest homework? Using javadriver
Note : I can not change the Data model.

Comment: By latest you mean the last one in the array?

Comment: @joao or possibly that this is a homework question from the mongodb university site. So you should be asking. What have you tried so far. Point 4 http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @NeilLunn true. What have you tried so far? :)

Comment: You want to find lowest score? I can show you shell command.

Comment: This is a MongoDB homework question, you should have done some basic knowledge with the driver before getting to this point, if not then you should probably go back some lessons

Answer (score -1):

Try this below -

```
x = db.students.aggregate([{
    "$unwind": "$scores"
}, {
    "$match": {
        "scores.type": "homework"
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "minscore": {
            "$min": "$scores.score"
        }
    }
}])
```

Your result document "x" contains an array field - lowest scores in the document